# SQL group records by date/hour/minute and join table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following 2 tables

TableA

```
|ParameterId|ParameterName|
|-----------|-------------|
|0          |Param_A      |
|1          |Param_B      |
|2          |Param_C      |
|3          |Param_D      |
```

TableB

```
|LogDateTime        |ParameterId|ParameterValue|
|-------------------|-----------|--------------|
|2019-01-29 00:00:12|0          |4             |
|2019-01-29 00:00:14|1          |2             |
|2019-01-29 00:00:17|2          |0             |
|2019-01-29 00:00:21|3          |1             |
|2019-01-30 00:01:13|0          |7             |
|2019-01-30 00:01:17|1          |3             |
|2019-01-30 00:01:22|2          |5             |
|2019-01-30 00:01:23|3          |9             |
|2019-01-31 00:02:20|0          |3             |
|2019-01-31 00:02:33|1          |0             |
|2019-01-31 00:02:41|2          |1             |
|2019-01-31 00:02:41|3          |6             |
```

How can I group the data in TableB by date, hour & minute and join with TableA to get a result as below:

```
|LogDateTime     |Param_A|Param_B|Param_C|Param_D|
|----------------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|2019-01-29 00:00|4      |2      |0      |1      |
|2019-01-30 00:01|7      |3      |5      |9      |
|2019-01-31 00:02|3      |0      |1      |6      |
```

Comment: Use `with` and union all then order by logdatetime, it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` to get the desired output like following query.

```
;WITH cte1 
     AS (SELECT B.*,P.parametername 
         FROM   @tableB B 
                INNER JOIN @tableA P 
                        ON B.parameterid = P.parameterid) 
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT 
       Cast(logdatetime AS SMALLDATETIME) AS logdatetime, 
       parametervalue, 
       parametername      
        FROM   cte1) AS SourceTable 
        PIVOT ( SUM(parametervalue) 
        FOR parametername IN ([Param_A],[Param_B], [Param_C],[Param_D] )) T
```

**[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/FVJ34749)**

**Note:**  If you want to `ROUND` the minutes when excluding the seconds and millisecond in that case you should do like following..

```
CAST(logdatetime  AS smalldatetime)
```

If you simply wants to truncate the seconds and milliseconds, you can change it like following.

```
CAST(DateAdd(minute, DateDiff(minute, 0, logdatetime), 0) AS smalldatetime)
```

If your `TableA` values are not fixed (can vary in future), in that case you need to go for a dynamic `PIVOT`.

Another simpler solution will be like following query using `CASE WHEN` if your Parameter are fixed.

```
 ;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Cast(logdatetime AS SMALLDATETIME) AS DT, 
                CASE WHEN parameterid = 0 THEN parametervalue  END  AS 'Param_A', 
                CASE WHEN parameterid = 1 THEN parametervalue  END  AS 'Param_B', 
                CASE WHEN parameterid = 2 THEN parametervalue  END  AS 'Param_C', 
                CASE WHEN parameterid = 3 THEN parametervalue  END  AS 'Param_D' 
         FROM   @TableB) 
SELECT dt                      AS LogDateTime, 
       Isnull(Sum(param_a), 0) AS Param_A, 
       Isnull(Sum(param_b), 0) AS Param_B, 
       Isnull(Sum(param_c), 0) AS Param_C, 
       Isnull(Sum(param_d), 0) AS Param_D 
FROM   cte 
GROUP  BY dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE and pivot tables, something like this:

```
with _prep as (
  select 
     LogDateTime=DateHourMinute(LogDateTime),
     ParameterName,
     ParameterValue
  from TableB b
  inner join TableA a on b.parameterID = a.parameterID
), 
select LogDateTime, Param_A,Param_B,Param_C,Param_D
 from (
  select LogDateTime, ParameterValue, ParameterName
  from _prep
) x 
pivot (
    max(ParameterValue) 
    for parameterName in (Param_A,Param_B,Param_C,Param_D)
) p
```

Please note that I omitted the CONTACT/rounding of datetime by using a mock DateHourMinute - this part is trivial but annoying to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to pivot your data. If parameter count is dynamic, you may need to generate dynamic statement.

Input:

```
-- Tables
CREATE TABLE #TableA (
   ParameterId int,
   ParameterName varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO #TableA
  (ParameterId, ParameterName)
VALUES  
   (0, 'Param_A'),
   (1, 'Param_B'),
   (2, 'Param_C'),
   (3, 'Param_D')

CREATE TABLE #TableB (
   LogDateTime datetime,
   ParameterId int, 
   ParameterValue int
)   
INSERT INTO #TableB
   (LogDateTime, ParameterId, ParameterValue)
VALUES   
   ('2019-01-29T00:00:12', 0, 4),
   ('2019-01-29T00:00:14', 1, 2),
   ('2019-01-29T00:00:17', 2, 0),
   ('2019-01-29T00:00:21', 3, 1),
   ('2019-01-30T00:01:13', 0, 7),
   ('2019-01-30T00:01:17', 1, 3),
   ('2019-01-30T00:01:22', 2, 5),
   ('2019-01-30T00:01:23', 3, 9),
   ('2019-01-31T00:02:20', 0, 3),
   ('2019-01-31T00:02:33', 1, 0),
   ('2019-01-31T00:02:41', 2, 1),
   ('2019-01-31T00:02:41', 3, 6)
```

Statement:

```
-- Statement   
SELECT
   -- Non-pivoted and pivoted columns
   [LogDateTime],
   [Param_A],
   [Param_B],
   [Param_C],
   [Param_D]
FROM (
    -- SELECT statement that produces the data
    SELECT 
       b.ParameterValue, 
       LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(19), b.LogDateTime, 120), 16) AS LogDateTime, 
       a.ParameterName
   FROM #TableB b
   LEFT JOIN #TableA a ON (b.ParameterID = a.ParameterID)
) d
PIVOT (
   -- Rotate data with PIVOT
   SUM ([ParameterValue])
   FOR [ParameterName] IN ([Param_A], [Param_B], [Param_C], [Param_D])
) p
```

Output:

```
LogDateTime         Param_A Param_B Param_C Param_D
2019-01-29 00:00    4       2       0       1
2019-01-30 00:01    7       3       5       9
2019-01-31 00:02    3       0       1       6
```